# DiscordJs: how to insert an image in the middle of text

Tags: typescript, image, text, discord, discord.js

I have a Discord bot that should send a welcome message in the next format:

```
Some text1 
<img1>
Some text2
<img2>
Some text3
```

I am using the next code for it (but in this case all images will be in the end of the message):

```
const user = await client.users.fetch('<user ID>');

await user.send({ content:"Some text1\n",
                  files: [{ attachment: "img1" }] });
```

So my question here, if it is possible somehow to change this code or use another one for creating a message in the required format? Preferable if it is all in one message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer to my question (it is not a perfect one but good enough).
Solution - [to use DiscordJs Embeds](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html#embeds). In this case it will be one Discord DM.

For example, for my case:

```
static getWelcomeMessage() : EmbedBuilder[] {
    const part1 = new EmbedBuilder()
        .setTitle('Welcome')
        .setDescription('<Some description>')
        .setImage('<Some image>')

    const part2 = new EmbedBuilder()
        .setDescription('<Some description>')
        .setImage('<Some image>')

    const part3 = new EmbedBuilder()
        .setDescription('<Some description>')
        .setImage('<Some image>')

    return [part1, part2, part3]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sadly Discord doesn't allow mixing images within text in a single message. You'll have to send separate messages to display text around each image.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As I see the best option for my case is to use DiscordJs Embeds.